how to use FlickPlayToggle and FlickLeftDuration in flutter
how to use FlickPlayToggle ,FlickLeftDuration, FlickVideoBuffer, FlickLeftDuration in flutter and integrating with flick sdk i tried to use them as widgets but i got an error of could not get the provider
just asking did not try any thing
